# How to debug node.js app running with TypeScript in WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, webstorm

How to debug node.js app running with TypeScript in WebStorm?

Comment: please see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/09/debugging-node-js-apps-in-webstorm/, *Debugging Node.js apps in TypeScript*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update **tsconfig.json** to add `sourceMap=true` property in `compilerOptions`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "target": "es6",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "lib"
  ]
}
```

In the **Edit Run/Debug Configuration**,

1. Write following line in *Node parameters* field. Don't forget to mention your port number! In my case it is *3000*

`--inspect=3000 --require ts-node/register`

2. Mention your entry **.ts** file in *Javascript file* field. In my case it is *bin/www.ts*

   [image: Edit Run/Debug Configurations]
3. Debug your newly created configuration

[image]